# How to Editing the WordPress Admin Menus only for Arabic Language Users

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-hook

I'm trying to change the WordPress Admin Menus for Arabic only, but when i use the following function it makes changes for all languages - English & Arabic

```
    <?php
/**
 * GeneratePress child theme functions and definitions.
 *
 * Add your custom PHP in this file.
 * Only edit this file if you have direct access to it on your server (to fix errors if they happen).
 */
function wd_admin_menu_rename() {
     global $menu; // Global to get menu array
     $menu[5][0] = 'أعلانات'; // Change name of posts to Ads
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wd_admin_menu_rename' );
```

**How can I change it only for Users with Arabic Dashboard?**

Answer (score 0):

```
function wd_admin_menu_rename() {
   // check for site language
   $lang = get_option('WPLANG');
   if($lang == 'ar')
   {
      global $menu; // Global to get menu array
      $menu[5][0] = 'أعلانات'; // Change name of posts to Ads
   }
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'wd_admin_menu_rename' );
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it. If it works i will mark your answer